# Quiver and relations for group algebras of p-groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, quivers

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group and $K$ a field of characteristic $p$.
$KG$ is isomorphic to a quiver algebra $KQ/I$ with admissible ideal $I$.

> Question 1: Does there always exist such an $I$ where the field coefficients are from $\{-1,0,1\}$?

This is true for abelian $G$, but I do not know many other examples.

> Question 2: Is it more general true that any group algebra over an algebraically closed field is Morita equivalent to $KQ/I$ with $I$ where the field coefficients are from $\{-1,0,1\}$?

Comment: What are the field coefficients of $I$?  Do you mean the coefficients of each element of a set of generators of $I$ all come from $\{-1, 0, 1\}$?

Comment: I suspect this is true and can be deduced from Jennings Theorem (see pages 93-95 of Benson's first volume on representation theory and cohomology).  You can take as a basis for $rad(KG)/rad(KG)^2$ (which is the augmentation ideal), those elements $g-1$ with $g$ not in the Frattini subgroup.  Then $(g-1)(h-1) = gh -1 -(g-1)-(h-1)$ and computations like these should let you determine the relations and see that they only have $0,,\pm 1$.

Comment: @LSpice yes this is what is meant.

Comment: Sorry, the basis for $rad(KG)/rad(KG)^2$ are the elements of the form $g-1$ where $g+\Phi(G)$ ranges over a basis for $G/\Phi(G)$ (were $\Phi(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup).

Comment: In general, the basis for $rad(KG)^r/rad(KG)^{r+1}$ is given by the  g- 1 ranging over coset reps of a basis for successive quotients in a certain central series for $G$.  This is why I think question 1 should have a positive answer.